# Is it possible to use CUDA C for object oriented programming?

Tags: c, oop, cuda

Is it possible to use CUDA C for object oriented programming?
Are there any classes in CUDA C like in C++?

Comment: CUDA C is misnamed.  It is CUDA C++, and you can use classes.

Comment: Appendix D of recent editions of "NVIDIA CUDA Programming Guide" describes exactly what C++ language features are supported by the device code compiler.

Comment: While it does support it to some extent, it does seem like it's worth calling out that it's probably questionable whether it's a good idea. Its intended for functional solutions and it may be worth investing some energy into functional patterns.

Answer (score 4):

`nvcc` since version 3.0 uses g++ (in Linux) for compiling host code, so you can use the whole set of C++ features for the host part.

For the device code it supports restricted set of C++. But I think in the future releases of CUDA it will be more complete.

Answer (score 4):

CUDA does support classes, however not all C++ features are available. CUDA C++ support has significantly evolved over the time. Here is a non-exhaustive list of supported features:

- C++ standards supported

  - CUDA 11 introduced C++17 support (see [release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html))
  - CUDA 12 now supports C++20 (see [release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/12.0.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html))
- Standard library support

  - libcu++ has many standard library functions available ([non-exhaustive list here](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/standard_api.html))
  - NVCC option `--expt-relaxed-constexpr` allows to use any `constexpr` host code in device code (powerful tool to reuse existing C++ code)
- Alternative compilers

  - NVIDIA offers `nvc++`, a compiler that allows to write parallel C++ code using C++17 execution policies ([more information on this page](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/compilers/c++-parallel-algorithms/index.html))

Answer (score 3):

CUDA compiler supports classes, inheritance, constructors, destructors, for all devices, although for some this support is not official.

Not all devices support (not inlined) function calls, recursion, virtual function calls, and even if if they do, that is a rather slow operation and I would strongly suggest you to avoid this unless it is rare in your code.

If I am not mistaken, there is no support for exceptions.

Similar, but a bit more broad question: [What are the real C++ language constructs supported by CUDA device code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899425/what-are-the-real-c-language-constructs-supported-by-cuda-device-code/5128193)